# ASP.NET charts trend line

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have basic bar charts showing some value (1 value per chart) on each day. The charts are rendered using standard MS ASP.NET charts.

Now I would like to add a trend line. Has somebody done such thing and would be so kind to give me some hints how to approach this task? I know how to add a line to the chart, just would like to know whether someone already did such thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, you want to show a line graph using the same values that each bar is drawn.
You can do this by adding one more series with chart type as line to the same chart area.
Make the `Y-axis` for the series as secondary and keep `X-axis` as primary (to keep same `X-axis` values for both Bar & line graph). Or you can also make `X-Axis` of this new series as Secondary (this will show labels on top of chart area) .